# Подскажите пожалуйста, как выровнить labe (Я согласен получать обновления на почту) относительно checkbox?

Tags: html, css

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #1B2473;
  color: #787878;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 26px 46px 26px 45px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.form__title {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 50px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 180%;
   margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.form__group {

}
.form__label-input {
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 100%;
}
.form__input {
   min-width: 509px;
   min-height: 49px;
   border: 2px solid #787878;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 32px;

 }
.form__input::placeholder {
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 129%;
   color: #787878;
 }
 .form__input:last-child {

 }
.form__label-checkbox {
   margin-right: 10px;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 114%;

}

.form__checkbox {
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
   border: 2px solid #787878;
   border-radius: 7px;
   margin-bottom: 52px;

}

.form__btn {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 67%;
  background: #1A226B;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px 56px 18px 55px;
}
.form__btn:hover {
  background: #3e4588;
}

 <form action="#" class="form">

    <h1 class="form__title">Вход</h1>

    <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input">Email</label>
        <input class="form__input" name="email" type="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input">Пароль</label>
        <input class="form__input" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль"> 
    </div>

    <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label-checkbox">
            <input class="form__checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
            Я согласен получать обновления на почту
        </label>
    </div>

    <button class="form__btn" type="submit">Войти</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подскажите пожалуйста, как выровнить label (Я согласен получать обновления на почту) относительно checkbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1352618/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-label-%d0%af-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be)

Comment: Вам ответили на этот вопрос уже, зачем его еще раз задавать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #1B2473;
  color: #787878;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 26px 46px 26px 45px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.form__title {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 50px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 180%;
   margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.form__group {

}
.form__label-input {
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 100%;
}
.form__input {
   min-width: 509px;
   min-height: 49px;
   border: 2px solid #787878;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 32px;

 }
.form__input::placeholder {
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 129%;
   color: #787878;
 }
 .form__input:last-child {

 }
.form__label-checkbox {
   margin-right: 10px;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 114%;
   margin-bottom: 52px;
   display: inline-flex;
   align-items: center;
   align-content: center;

}

.form__checkbox {
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
   border: 2px solid #787878;
   border-radius: 7px;
   margin-right: 10px;
}

.form__btn {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 67%;
  background: #1A226B;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px 56px 18px 55px;
}
.form__btn:hover {
  background: #3e4588;
}
```

```html
 <form action="#" class="form">

    <h1 class="form__title">Вход</h1>

    <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input">Email</label>
        <input class="form__input" name="email" type="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input">Пароль</label>
        <input class="form__input" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль"> 
    </div>

    <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label-checkbox">
            <input class="form__checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
            Я согласен получать обновления на почту
        </label>
    </div>

    <button class="form__btn" type="submit">Войти</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но почему то не работает(

Comment: @ИгорьТрубников а стили те же, которые я указала?

Comment: @ИгорьТрубников можно где то увидеть то, что сейчас происходит на сайте? либо в песочнице?

Comment: display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
Не работают((((

Comment: @ИгорьТрубников там также был убран нижний маргин у .form__checkbox , советую сверить все стили. Стили поддерживаются всеми браузерами, они не могут не работать, что то делаете не так

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло)